# How do you use event delegation to switch Font Awesome 5 SVG icons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm attempting to switch Font Awesome SVG icons on click using event delegation. Most of the info I've found only references "querySelector." I've already gone through the [Font Awesome documentation here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/jquery), which is a reference to jQuery. As mentioned, it uses "querySelector," but no mention of event delegation. I'm also creating this with vanilla JS, but I get what they are saying with the jQuery example.

I've [found a couple of tutorials](https://themightyprogrammer.dev/snippet/changing-svg-icon) that switch the SVG icon using a conditional statement, but again it references the use of "querySelector" and not event delegation. It would be great to see an example like this with event delegation instead of "querySelector."

I do believe the issue is related to how event delegation is switching its target after the icon has been switched. So, I can get the icon to switch initially, but after that switch the event is no longer attached to the original target `<i class="fal fa-circle dot"></i>` and drills down inside the SVG instead of selecting it directly.

```
const list = document.querySelector('.todo__list');
list.addEventListener('click', completeTask);

function completeTask(event) {
    const targetThis = event.target;

    const doneIcon = targetThis.parentElement;
    
    if (doneIcon.matches('.todo__done-icon')) {
        console.log('match found');
        console.log(doneIcon.children[0].dataset.prefix);
        if (doneIcon.children[0].dataset.prefix === 'fal') {
            console.log('has fal');
            doneIcon.children[0].setAttribute('data-prefix', 'fas');
        }
        else if (doneIcon.children[0].dataset.prefix === 'fas') {
            console.log('has fas');
            doneIcon.children[0].setAttribute('data-prefix', 'fal');
        }
        
    }
}
```

I should note that I am creating a To Do list and so elements are created dynamically after clicking submit using "createElement." For example, the output of the HTML after submitting a task looks like this. The UL is the only static HTML before appending these elements.

```
<ul class="todo__list">
   <li class="todo__list-item">
      <div class="todo__list-text-div"><p class="todo__list-text">List Item</p></div>
      <div class="todo__done-icon"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-circle fa-w-16 dot" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="circle" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8zm216 248c0 118.7-96.1 216-216 216-118.7 0-216-96.1-216-216 0-118.7 96.1-216 216-216 118.7 0 216 96.1 216 216z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fal fa-circle dot"></i> Font Awesome fontawesome.com --></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE: [Here is the link to my CodePen](https://codepen.io/burtcrismore/pen/4d22ff19b367e326d4dcd875c7353ae9) to show how on first click it targets the SVG, but after the icon switches, the target changes to the path. Check out the console log I have set up.

Comment: Can you link your website or show it with a code Snippet.

Comment: Here's my CodePen. If you look at the console log you can see how the first click on the SVG targets the SVG. The second click on that switched SVG then targets the path which is the child of the SVG instead of the SVG itself. https://codepen.io/burtcrismore/pen/4d22ff19b367e326d4dcd875c7353ae9